# Fix for antiClickJacking vulnerability for web application

Tags: tomcat, clickjacking

I have two web applications running on Apache tomcat server. There are two vulnerabilities identified by our security team.

> *85582 - Web Application Potentially Vulnerable to Clickjacking*

I have gone through some sites as we have to fix this problem. Its been said that we can go with either client side or server side prevention. I understood that for server side prevention we need to add "HTTP Header sercurity Filter" in tomcat web.xml file.

Can anyone tell which way I need to choose for this and how? 
If I need to go for the adding filter, is that alone enough or I need to do anything extra?

Any help on this will be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherSchultz. I am trying to find the ways as am new to this topic totally. My question is, If i go with "HTTP header security filter" in tomcat, will that alone is enough to do ?

Comment: Thanks for information @ChristopherSchultz

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to mitigate vulnerabilities such as clickjacking. Which technique were you hoping to use? Even Tomcat's [HTTP Header Security Filter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/filter.html#HTTP_Header_Security_Filter) has many options. Usually, clickjacking is made possible by an XSS bug in the application or some other serious application problem (or related product, such as an ad hosted on the page).

Enabling the HTTP Header Security Filter, however, is not enough. Your application has to be secure as well. The anti-clickjacking features of the web browser (which are merely enabled using these headers) are a safety net for servers that aren't careful about the content they send to the browser. You need to make sure that there are no e.g. XSS vulnerabilities in your application as well.